# Align three divs: one of them containing an image and the other two text

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align three divs side by side. The center div contains a href with image, that expands links to edit text. The problem is that I am unable to verticaly align the contents of those divs. The left, right and center div contents should all be verticaly aligned in the middle like:

[right]
    [left] [center] [right]
                         [right]

It might also look something like:

[left]
    [left]              [right]
    [left] [center] [right]
    [left]              [right]
    [left]

But now it looks like:

[left] [center] [right]
    [left]              [right]
    [left]

The edit-content div lies

This is the code so far:

```
<div id="search-result" class="accordion">
            <div class="search-result-left">
                <p>CEPT, Conference Europ&eacute;enne des Adminidstra-</p>
                <p>tion Despostes et des T&eacute;l&eacute;communications</p>
            </div>
            <div class="search-result-right">
                <p>Evropsko združenje po&scaron;tnih in telekomunikaci-</p>
                <p>jskih organizacij</p>
            </div>
            <div class="search-result-center">
                <a href="#" class="acc"><img src="CSS/images/arrow_wr.gif"/></a>
            </div>
        <div class="edit-content">
            <p><a href="#">edit</a> - 
                <a href="#">comment</a> - 
                <a href="#">translate</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
#all-search-results {
font-size: 14px;
color: #000000;
width: 730px;
margin: 0 auto;
line-height: 4px;
}
.search-result-left {
text-align: right;
float: left;
width: 335px;
}
.search-result-center {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 60px;
}
.search-result-center img{
vertical-align: bottom;
}
.search-result-right {
text-align: left;
float: right;
width: 335px;
}
.edit-content{
color: #669900;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.edit-content a {
color: #669900;
}
```

Comment: There have been made a LOT of posts about vertically centering a div. Please use the search mechanism on this website or refer to http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html  (first hit I got on Google).

Comment: There are better ways to do it than that.

Comment: I was also looking that exact page, but thats not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To center align the contents of a `div` I've done this:

```
.myDiv {
    min-height: 10em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you're gunna have to do some tweaking but the idea is you split it into three parts

top
middle
Bottom

you can then float the first block over to the right in the top block,
then shove 3 blocks in the middle
then float another one to the right inside the bottom block.
(if my code dosn't work sorry I haven't tested it, but the idea is there)

It's always best to break things up in what I call 'wraps'.

```
.Wrap{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; width: auto;
    background: red;
}
.rightContent{
    float: right;
    height: 100px; width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
#left{
    float: left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: green;
}
#center{
    float: left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: yellow;
}
#right{
    float: left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: grey;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="rightContent">top right</div>
</div>

<div class="Wrap">
    <div id="left">mid left</div>
    <div id="center">mid center</div>
    <div id="right">mid right</div>
</div>

<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="rightContent">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is basicaly what I have now. But I don't want to have a fixed height. I was thinking to align those three divs verticaly in the middle. If I remove the height atribute from your solution, the divs are aligned at the top. The other solution would be to have a fixed height for those three divs, and to make the divs content to bo verticaly aligned in the middle, but I was hoping for the first option if possible:) Sorry for my english by the way, I hope there is someone who understands itXD

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example you can refer this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```